# How can I run my playbooks locally without ssh in Ansible?

Tags: ssh, ansible, localhost, ansible-inventory

I want to run my playbooks on localhost without ssh in Ansible. How can I do that? I have a virtual machine. I want it to run locally on that machine.

Answer (score 5):

Use `connection: local`. See [Local playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks). For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - command: echo Hello World!
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  result.stdout: Hello World!
```

---

If you want to debug the connection run the playbook with triple `-vvv` option

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -vvv
```

You'll see details of the connection in the output, e.g.

```yaml
...
TASK [command] ************************************************************
task path: /scratch/playbook.yml:4
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
...
```

Comment: Thank you. But now I got an error.